# No able to get Present cell value on cell leav event in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

When I am trying to get the value of the present cell when I am leaving that cell, I am not able to get the value of that cell. My code is in Cell_Leave event

```
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 5)
        {
            double netVal;
            double.TryParse(dgvRegister.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString(), out netVal);

            double Vat;
            double.TryParse(dgvRegister.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString(), out Vat);

            string amt = ((netVal / 100) * Vat).ToString();
        }
```

In this case I am getting cells[4] value, when I came to cells[5].value I am getting **null value**. Why am I getting a null value? Please help me find a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to change the `Value` to `EditedFormattedValue`

```
dgvRegister.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].EditedFormattedValue.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on spajce's answer, instead of `dgvRegister.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4]`, you could also use [`CurrentCell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell.aspx) property of the `DataGridView` directly. A little less code.

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString();
```

*btw thanks to spajce for introducing `EditedFormattedValue` to me. I did not know that.*